# Masscan, scan multiple ranges from txt file

Tags: ip, nmap

I have txt file with

```
x.x.x.x/22
x.x.x.x/23
x.x.x.x/24
```

Etc etc etc

How can i get masscan to read these ranges, and perform a scan on all of them ?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo masscan -p80 -iL file_name.txt`

You can customise your port number. The scan must be run in the same directory where you created your text file.
*scan output-*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7lae.png)